# Can I provide parameters to a custom model binder referenced in an attribute in .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a custom model binder implementing IModelBinder and want to apply it to my view models using attributes. e.g.:

```
namespace TestWebApp.Models
{
    public class ExperimentalViewModel
    {
        [ModelBinder(typeof(MandatoryIntBinder))]
        public int MandatoryInt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The reason for this is so that I can return my own error messages if model binding fails. To do that nicely I would like to pass in a friendly name for the field being bound to the instance of MandatoryIntBinder being used. Something like:

```
[ModelBinderWithParameters(typeof(MandatoryIntBinder), "Test mandatory int")]
```

Is that possible?

A better way of generating custom model binding errors would also be a great solution for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to pass in a friendly name for the field being bound to the instance of MandatoryIntBinder being used

You'll need to add it to the BindingContext somehow. Doing this in general is a bit fiddly, but for the specific case of passing in a friendly name, this is already catered for by the `ModelBinderAttribute` that you're using.

If you specify the `Name` property on the attibute like so:

```cs
    namespace TestWebApp.Models
    {
        public class ExperimentalViewModel
        {
            [ModelBinder(typeof(MandatoryIntBinder), Name = "Test Mandatory Int")]
            public int MandatoryInt { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

This will then be available inside your custom model binder's `BindModelAsync` as `bindingContext.BinderModelName`.

If you still need to use the original model name from inside your binder (e.g. to get the value out of the form collection) you can access it via `bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Name` or `bindingContext.ModelMetadata.PropertyName`.

---

> Can I provide parameters to a custom model binder referenced in an attribute in .Net Core?

`Name` is the only other property on `ModelBinderAttribute`. If you want to pass arbitrary parameters to your custom binder for individual properties, you can add them via additional attributes, which can be accessed from your model binder in one the following ways:

1. Inside your custom binder, cast `bindingContext.ModelMetadata` to `DefaultModelMetadata` and access its `Attributes` property directly (this is arguably brittle, but practically very unlikely to break)
2. Implement your own IMetadataDetailsProvider, which can look at the attributes and populate the metadata available to the binder

Note that there are three kinds of IMetadataDetailsProvider: `IBindingMetadataProvider`, `IDisplayMetadataProvider`, and `IValidationMetadataProvider`.

- `IBindingMetadataProvider` seems like the most appropriate, but it can only populate `BindingMetadata` which only has a handful of writable properties (most of which can be set by other attributes via the built-in default metadata providers).
- `IDisplayMetadataProvider` can populate `DisplayMetadata`, which contains an `IDictionary<object,object> AdditionalValues` property, which can contain arbitrary data. Note that this data will also be available in views (which you might not specifically want, but shouldn't cause any problems).
- `IValidationMetadataProvider` can populate `ValidationMetadata`, which contains an `IList<object> ValidatorMetadata` property, which can contain arbitrary data. Obviously more appropriate for usage during validation, but the fact that it's an IList rather than an IDictionary makes it slightly less convenient to pull data back out.

Which of `IDisplayMetadataProvider` or `IValidationMetadataProvider` to use depends on your exact use case. `IDisplayMetadataProvider` enables slightly more generic usage if you want to support varying sets of parameters. Both interfaces support a more strongly-typed approach with a fixed set of parameters.

#### Using IValidatorMetadataProvider

You need a way to identify the correct value to pull out of the `IList<object> ValidatorMetadata` property. As long as you limit yourself to a single instance of your custom attribute, you could just add the attribute itself to the list, and then identify it by type, as follows:

Attribute

```cs
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustomValidationAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public CustomValidationAttribute()
        {
        }

        public string CustomErrorName { get; set; }
    }
```

Provider

```cs
    public class CustomValidationAttributeProvider : IValidationMetadataProvider
    {
        public void CreateValidationMetadata(ValidationMetadataProviderContext context)
        {
            var attribute = context.Attributes.OfType<CustomValidationAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                context.ValidationMetadata.ValidatorMetadata.Add(attribute);
            }
        }
    }
```

Access in custom binder

```cs
    public class MandatoryIntBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var customValidationAttribute = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ValidatorMetadata.OfType<CustomValidationAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Usage on model

```
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MandatoryIntBinder))]
    [CustomValidation(CustomErrorName = "Test mandatory int")]
    public int MandatoryInt { get; set; }
```

Registration of provider

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new CustomValidationAttributeProvider()));
        }
```

#### Using IDisplayMetadataProvider

You can use the above approach with IDisplayMetadataProvider instead of IValidatorMetadataProvider if IDisplayMetadataProvider seems more appropriate for your use case.

The fact that IDisplayMetadataProvider populates a dictionary rather than a list also enables a more generic approach (but unless you specifically need this, the more strongly-typed approach above is probably preferable). We can pass generic additional parameters to a custom model binder via a custom IDisplayMetadataProvider as follows:

Attribute

```cs
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AdditionalMetadataValueAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public AdditionalMetadataValueAttribute(object key, object value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }

        public object Key { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Provider

```cs
    public class AdditionalMetadataValuesProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
    {
        public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
        {
            foreach (var attribute in context.Attributes.OfType<AdditionalMetadataValueAttribute>())
            {
                context.DisplayMetadata.AdditionalValues.Add(attribute.Key, attribute.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Access in custom binder

```cs
    public class MandatoryIntBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public const string ErrorNameKey = "ScratchWebApp.Models.MandatoryIntBinder.ErrorNameKey";
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var errorName = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.GetValueOrDefault(ErrorNameKey) as string;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Usage on model

```cs
        [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MandatoryIntBinder))]
        [AdditionalMetadataValue(MandatoryIntBinder.ErrorNameKey, "Test mandatory int")]
        public int MandatoryInt { get; set; }
```

Registration of provider

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new AdditionalMetadataValuesProvider()));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will work if I can get away with only a single error message for failed binding. I suspect, I'll need to have different messages for different error cases - hence the custom model binder.

Comment: Ah, so your custom binder is responsible for the error message but you just need to specify a friendly name for the property? This should also be possible with a custom metadata details provider (you can set context.BindingMetadata.ModelName). Or there might already be an attribute that BindingContext respects.

Comment: In fact, the `Name` property of the `ModelBinder` attribute will be available to your custom binder as `bindingContext.BinderModelName`. So you could just do `[ModelBinder(typeof(MandatoryIntBinder), Name = "Test mandatory int"))]`

Comment: (Updated above because I think that's a better answer to your actual question)