# Asp.net Core MVC ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues add function

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am upgrading MVC5 to Asp.Net Core 3 MVC and just found that ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues has been changed to IReadOnlyDictionary.  We have stored information in additionalValues before.  What is the alternative solution now?

Thanks in advance.
Wilson

Answer (score 0):

> What is the alternative solution now?

You could use `ViewData` and `ViewBag`  to pass data to a view in ASP.NET Core.

### **ViewData**

is a property of the Controller Base class, which returns a `ViewDataDictionary` object.
The `ViewDataDictionary` is a dictionary object which allows us to store key-value pairs. The key must be a case-insensitive string. To pass data to the view, you can assign values to the dictionary using the Key. You can store any number of items as needed in the `ViewData`.

The data stored in the `ViewData` object exists only during the current request. As soon as the view is generated and sent to the client, the `Viewdata` object is cleared.

The following is an example that sets values for a Title using `ViewData` in an action:

**1. Codes in Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Hello World!";
    return View();
}
```

**2. Codes in View**

```
@ViewData["Greeting"]
```

### **ViewBag**

isn't available in Razor Pages.  `ViewBag` is a DynamicViewData object that provides dynamic access to the objects stored in `ViewData`. `ViewBag` can be more convenient to work with, since it doesn't require casting. The following example shows how to use `ViewBag` with the same result as using `ViewData` above:

**1. Codes in Controller**

```
public IActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ViewBag.Greeting = "Hello";

    return View();
}
```

**2. Codes in View**

```
@ViewBag.Greeting World!
```

Here you can find more information like below in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#passing-data-to-views).

- **ViewData attribute** - Another approach that uses the `ViewDataDictionary` is `ViewDataAttribute`.
- Using ViewData and ViewBag **simultaneously**
- Summary of the **differences** between ViewData and ViewBag
- **When** to use ViewData or ViewBag
- Strongly typed data (**ViewModel**)

Comment: Thanks Michael. But we are using ModelMetadata.AdditionalData in HtmlHelper and it is something like custom attribute.

Comment: Maybe you can find the reason why ModelMetadata attribute doesn't existed anymore [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7988).

Comment: Thanks.  IDisplayMetadataProvider is one of the options now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920515/can-i-provide-parameters-to-a-custom-model-binder-referenced-in-an-attribute-in