# DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I am migrating a project from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core 6.0.

I have the following class in the ASP.NET MVC project:

```
public class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        var textAreaAttribute = attributes.SingleOrDefault(a => typeof(TextAreaAttribute) == a.GetType());

        if (textAreaAttribute != null)
        {
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("TextArea", null);
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("Rows", ((TextAreaAttribute)textAreaAttribute).Rows);
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("Columns", ((TextAreaAttribute)textAreaAttribute).Columns);
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("MaxLength", ((TextAreaAttribute)textAreaAttribute).MaxLength);
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("Placeholder", ((TextAreaAttribute)textAreaAttribute).Placeholder);
        }

        var textInputAttribute = attributes.SingleOrDefault(a => typeof(TextInputAttribute) == a.GetType());

        if (textInputAttribute != null)
        {
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("TextInput", null);
            metadata.AdditionalValues.Add("MaxLength", ((TextInputAttribute)textInputAttribute).MaxLength);
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent of this in ASP.NET Core 6.0?

One use case for this:

```
[TextInput(MaxLength = 10)] // limit number of field input characters to 10
```

TextInput:

```
public class TextInputAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> OptionalAttributes()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "MaxLength", MaxLength }
        };
    }
}
```

The following is set in the ASP.NET MVC project Global.asax file:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomModelMetadataProvider();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` in .net core, it only has [`IModelMetadataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.imodelmetadataprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0). You may notice that it provides [`DefaultModelMetadataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.metadata.defaultmodelmetadataprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0) as base class:

```
public class MyModelMetadataProvider : DefaultModelMetadataProvider
{
    public MyModelMetadataProvider(ICompositeMetadataDetailsProvider detailsProvider) : base(detailsProvider)
    {
    }

    protected override DefaultMetadataDetails[] CreatePropertyDetails(ModelMetadataIdentity key)
    {
        var defaultPropertyDetails = base.CreatePropertyDetails(key);

        var attributes = defaultPropertyDetails[0].ModelAttributes.PropertyAttributes;

        var metadata = base.CreateModelMetadata(defaultPropertyDetails[0]);

        var textInputAttribute = attributes.SingleOrDefault(a => typeof(TextInputAttribute) == a.GetType());

        if (textInputAttribute != null)
        {
            //do something
        }

        return defaultPropertyDetails;
    }
}
```

But in `DefaultModelMetadataProvider`, `AdditionalValues` is a read-only property, so according to your code, the alternative should be [`IDisplayMetadataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.metadata.idisplaymetadataprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```
public class AdditionalMetadataValuesProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in context.Attributes.OfType<AdditionalMetadataValueAttribute>())
        {
            context.DisplayMetadata.AdditionalValues.Add(attribute.Key, attribute.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Register in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDisplayMetadataProvider, AdditionalMetadataValuesProvider>();
```

For more details, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59921799/18789859).